# Browser compatibility

Tags: java, asp.net, cross-browser

Just wanted to know if ASP.NET supports other browsers as well as it supports Internet explorer?
Also, does Spring/Java framework for a web platform would them in any better way…?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ASP.NET, the code is all server side, so browsers never even know the difference.

The only things that would affect browser compatibility really would be the generated HTML from the built-in controls and the associated javascript that goes along with them.  Personally, I've never seen any problems with those.

The closest thing to a problem that I've run into is with the generated "ID" elements for server controls.  Makes it pretty hard to write CSS and Javascript that uses element ID's, so you usually need to use classes instead.  But that's not a browser issue as much as just a general PITA.  Note that if you use ASP.NET MVC, the "ID" issue is no longer a concern.

Answer (score 0):

It depends more on slicing than on ASP.NET itself. CSS and javascript incompatibilities are not server side related.
If talking about ASP.NET MVC than there is not difference at all between an asp.net mvc generated page and an PHP one.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question, browsers only read the output from ASP.Net (the HTML/Scripts), so it is not really aware of what built the page, the server builds it and serves it up.